# What hl7 version is required for meaningful use 3?

Tags: amazon-emr, hl7, medical

I am working on an EHR application and it has already implemented some version of HL7. We are going to certify this EHR for Meaningful use 3 (mu3).

Any idea what version of HL7 will be required for meaningful use 3 (mu3) certification?

I have worked on edi before, never worked in hl7, any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: You tagged the question as openehr, that is wrong. Your question has nothing to do with openehr. You also tagged it with hl7, but it cannot be answered in that context either. HL7 is not anymore a single standard with a single version, but it is a group of standards, like FHIR, CDA. You tagged the question with edi, but it is not about edi. It has nothing to do with HL7 nor OpenEhr. EDI is obsoleet since about the year 2000 and only some old protocols use it still because of legacy support. So I removed some unappropriate tags from your question

Answer (score 0):

Meaningful Use is made of up several different objectives, with multiple different HL7 standards unerpinning them. [This is comprehensive list](https://www.healthit.gov/topic/certification/2015-standards-hub) of the standards that are referenced in each section.

[Here is a link to the full 2015 certification criteria](https://www.federalregister.gov/documents/2015/10/16/2015-25597/2015-edition-health-information-technology-health-it-certification-criteria-2015-edition-base#h-94).

The cliff notes version is that you will do some CDA, HL7v2, and possibly FHIR depending on what your product does.